# MySQL column can't reference self column

Tags: mysql

I create test like this

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT UNSIGNED UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  parent_id INT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES test(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = INNODB;
```

but get error

> #3780 - Referencing column 'parent_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'test_ibfk_1' are incompatible.

I need parent_id reference self id (if parent_id not null), how do I fix it?

thank every help.

Comment: They have to be the same data type. `id` is `INT UNSIGNED`, but `parent_id` is `INT`.

Comment: Great insight! It works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thank Barmar's comment, here are right the way:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT UNSIGNED UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  parent_id INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES test(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Cheers!

Comment: 'Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. The size and sign of fixed precision types such as INTEGER and DECIMAL must be the same' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html